# IIS application pool recycling and native assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-assembly

I have an application that runs under IIS, the application has three assemblies: a managed assembly, a mixed assembly and a native dll. 
The managed assembly exposes a singleton object `MaS` that wraps a native singleton `NaS` via a mixed singleton `MiS` (C++/CLI).

**PROBLEM**

When IIS recycles the application pool, the managed singleton `MaS` seem to go away and its assembly unloaded from the APPDOMAIN and so does the mixed one `MiS`. However, the native singleton `NaS` sticks around and does not get destroyed. This is problematic in my case as when the application is recycled and loaded again, the managed singleton, now `MaS1` gets confused as it finds an already existing native singleton `NaS` in memory.

**QUESTION**

How are native dlls handled at application pool recycles? Do they get unloaded?

Comment: I would not expect non-COM native object to be magically destroyed because some technically unrelated "manage assembly" get unloaded on AppDomain recycle. Obviously in-process objects will be destroyed on AppPool (process) recycle... Which contradicts to your observation and makes me completely confused...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Totally agree with you! I think it is disrespect to .NET to call these evil binaries, assemblies. Will update my post. Thank you

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Exactly! all managed objects are destroyed, the native ones stick in memory and don't get destroyed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appdomain recycling does not unload appdomain, it loads a new domain, and subsequent requests are handled by a new appdomain.

Old appdomain unloads only when finished processing the already accepted requests.

It's also possible that an old appdomain fail to unload if it performs a blocking operation in unmanaged code.

As a workaround you could disable apppool recycle and configure ovelapping worker processes.
Separate worker process will isolate the unmanaged dll state for sure.

You can easily check that unmanaged dll has it's state shared between appdomains with following code:

Managed code:

```
[DllImport("Win32Library.dll")]
public static extern Int16 inc();

private readonly static DateTime AppDomainStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;

public ActionResult Counter()
{
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { counter = inc(), appDomainId = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id, started = AppDomainStarted.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Unmanaged code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) short inc();

short inc()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    return counter++;
}
```

Just recompile your aspnet code and refresh browser to see incrementing result in counter, and appdomain id inside the working process. Make sure you use IISExpress for debugging.

Comment: +1. Hm ok, so when the new app domain is loaded, a new managed singleton is created without its native counter part because it is already in memory is this correct? Do these app domain share all loaded native objects or does every app domain have its own set of native objects?

Comment: It's shared among all the appdomains in a worker process. You need to recycle the worker process to reinitialize.

Comment: I guess this applies only IIS is configured to load all subsequent app domains into the same process right?

Comment: Its by default. You need to examine the available settings in the apppool. Appdomains recycle routinely and the worker processes are spawned sparringly. Usually worker processes are recycled for fail protection reasons.